# Paragraph style in PHP string

Tags: php

If I have like that format string, how I can turn this like one well formatted paragraph with PHP an example like text-align: justify in CSS and full-width of browser window?

```
<?php

$text = "It is a long 
established fact that a reader 
will be distracted 
by the readable content of a 
page when looking at its layout. 
The point of using Lorem Ipsum 
is that it has a 
more-or-less normal distribution of 
letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, 
content here', making it look like readable English. 
Many desktop publishing packages and web 
page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their 
default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' 
will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. 
Various versions have evolved over the years, 
sometimes by accident, sometimes on 
purpose (injected humour and the like).
";
?>
```

**In result I want to turn this paragraph to this format:**

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

Comment: Remove the /n/r characters from $text (they are not visible in your first text.)

Answer (score 1):

PHP handles very little in so far as formatting and displaying of text. When you store the above text into the $text object there, outputting it directly into the browser window will show it as you have it just below. You'll want to use CSS and HTML to format the text you output from your PHP.

Also, all those line breaks that you see as you assign them to the $text object won't be preserved by PHP. You have to explicitly declare that you want new lines when you store the text string.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your variable in a `<p>` tag and apply style

```
<?php

$text = "It is a long 
established fact that a reader 
will be distracted 
by the readable content of a 
page when looking at its layout. 
The point of using Lorem Ipsum 
is that it has a 
more-or-less normal distribution of 
letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, 
content here', making it look like readable English. 
Many desktop publishing packages and web 
page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their 
default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' 
will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. 
Various versions have evolved over the years, 
sometimes by accident, sometimes on 
purpose (injected humour and the like).
";

$text = "<p style='text-align:justify'>$text</p>";

echo $text;
```

```html
<p style='text-align:justify'>It is a long 
established fact that a reader 
will be distracted 
by the readable content of a 
page when looking at its layout. 
The point of using Lorem Ipsum 
is that it has a 
more-or-less normal distribution of 
letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, 
content here', making it look like readable English. 
Many desktop publishing packages and web 
page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their 
default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' 
will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. 
Various versions have evolved over the years, 
sometimes by accident, sometimes on 
purpose (injected humour and the like).
</p>
```

Comment: I know that :) but i don't what to use css solutions. I need to know how to do that with php functions

Comment: @CihanZengin PHP is a server side script, capable of doing server level operation. Front end presentation is handled by CSS.

Comment: rendering is done entirely client side in the browser, you have no control over that with php. all you can do is pass it style/css

Answer (score 0):

You can store you paragraph as a string like that and remove all trialling white space using RegExp.

$text = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $text);